# Overlapping song sounds on my music player

Tags: java, android, mobile

I developed a music player using Java in Android Studio. However, when I press the back button on the player and then click on another song in the Recycler View, two music sounds overlap. Please do not suggest using methods like OnDestroy because I want the current song to keep playing when the screen is turned off or when the user goes back, and I only want it to stop when another song is played. The main reason for the problem is that when playing any song, starting another song uses a different MediaPlayer element. How can I solve this?

This is my AudioPlayer code:

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import android.content.Intent; import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever; import android.media.MediaPlayer; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.Handler; import android.view.View; import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.SeekBar; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide; import com.connunity.rhythmia.R.drawable;

import java.io.IOException; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Random; import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AudioPlayer extends AppCompatActivity { Boolean shuffle = false; Boolean repeat = false; MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); TextView title, artist, album, currentTime, actualTime; ImageView previous, play, next, closeAct, shuffleBtn, repeatBtn; ImageView songIcon; ArrayList<AudioModel> songArray; AudioModel currentSong; SeekBar seekBar; Intent listening;
public static String convertTime(String duration) {
    long millis = Long.parseLong(duration);
    return String.format("%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audioplayer);
    shuffleBtn = findViewById(R.id.shuffleButton);
    repeatBtn = findViewById(R.id.repeatButton);
    listening = new Intent(AudioPlayer.this, MainActivity.class);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    title = findViewById(R.id.playerSongName);
    artist = findViewById(R.id.playerArtistName);
    album = findViewById(R.id.playerAlbumName);
    currentTime = findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
    actualTime = findViewById(R.id.songActualTime);
    next = findViewById(R.id.playernext);
    previous = findViewById(R.id.playerprevious);
    play = findViewById(R.id.playAndPauseButton);
    closeAct = findViewById(R.id.playerCloseActButton);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);
    songArray = (ArrayList<AudioModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("List");
    title.setSelected(true);
    setCurrentSong();
    AudioPlayer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                listening.putExtra("seekBar", seekBar.getProgress());
                currentTime.setText(convertTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + ""));
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    play.setImageResource(drawable.pausebutton);
                } else {
                    play.setImageResource(drawable.playingbutton);
                }
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    });
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer.this, "Shuffle clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (shuffle) {
                shuffleBtn.setImageResource(drawable.shuffle_off);
                shuffle = false;
            }else{
                shuffleBtn.setImageResource(drawable.shuffle_on);
                shuffle = true;
                repeat = false;
                repeatBtn.setImageResource(drawable.repeat_off);
            }
        }

    });
repeatBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(repeat){
            repeat = false;
            repeatBtn.setImageResource(drawable.repeat_off);
        }
        else {repeat = true;
            shuffle = false;
            shuffleBtn.setImageResource(drawable.shuffle_off);
        repeatBtn.setImageResource(drawable.repeat_on);}
    }
});
}


public void setCurrentSong() {
    this.currentSong = songArray.get(TMediaPlayer.currentIndex);
    title.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
    artist.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
    album.setText(currentSong.getAlbum());
    currentTime.setText(convertTime(currentSong.getDuration()));
    byte[] image = getSongIcon(currentSong.getPath());
    try {
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(songIcon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Olmadı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    play.setOnClickListener(v -> playAndPauseMusic());
    next.setOnClickListener(v -> nextMusic());
    previous.setOnClickListener(v -> previousMusic());
    next.setOnLongClickListener(v -> forward5());
    previous.setOnLongClickListener(v -> backTo5());
    listening.putExtra("name", currentSong.getTitle());
    listening.putExtra("artist", currentSong.getArtist());
    playMusic();

}

void playMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentSong.getPath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            nextMusic();
        }
    });
}

void nextMusic() {
    if (TMediaPlayer.currentIndex == songArray.size() - 1) {
        TMediaPlayer.currentIndex = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (shuffle){playRandom();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    setCurrentSong();}
    if (repeat){
        TMediaPlayer.currentIndex-=1;
    }
    TMediaPlayer.currentIndex += 1;
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    setCurrentSong();
}

void previousMusic() {
    if (TMediaPlayer.currentIndex == 0) {
        TMediaPlayer.currentIndex = songArray.size();
        return;
    }
    TMediaPlayer.currentIndex -= 1;
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    setCurrentSong();
}

boolean forward5() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int forwardTime = 5000;
        if (currentPosition + forwardTime <= duration) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + forwardTime);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean backTo5() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int backwardTime = 5000;
        if (currentPosition - backwardTime >= 0) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition - backwardTime);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void playAndPauseMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else mediaPlayer.start();
}

private byte[] getSongIcon(String uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(uri);
    byte[] icon = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    try {
        retriever.release();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return icon;
}

void playRandom() {
    Random r = new Random();
    TMediaPlayer.currentIndex = r.nextInt(songArray.size());
}
```

}`

Comment: Don't use a different MediaPlayer.  MediaPlayer is expensive, you shouldn't have more than one of them per Activity.

Comment: I didn't use more than one. when I choose another item in RecView AudioPlayer class work again.